# log4php : Cannot create log file

Tags: php, log4php

I use log4php to write file logs. Here is the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/">
    <appender name="default" class="LoggerAppenderDailyFile">
        <layout class="LoggerLayoutPattern">
            <param name="conversionPattern" value="%date %logger %-5level %msg%n" />
        </layout>
        <param name="file" value="/path/to/log/register-%s.log" />
        <param name="datePattern" value="Y-m-d" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="info" />
        <appender_ref ref="default" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And here is the initialization codes in PHP :

```
require_once('/path/to/log4php/Logger.php');
require_once('/path/to/log4php.xml');
$logger = Logger::getLogger(basename(__FILE__));
$logger->info('Testing');
```

the folder permission is set to 777 ( it's a Ubuntu Linux server ), but the log file didn't create. How do I debug the log4php?

Comment: Did you try to use `Logger::configure('/path/to/log4php.xml');` instead of require?

Comment: Just tried. No luck. the log still does not create.

Comment: thats super strange i just downloaded log4php and used your code with replacement of that `Logger::configure('/path/to/log4php.xml');` insead of require just before calling `$logger = Logger::getLogger(basename(__FILE__));` and i got log written successfully. What does error_logs say?

Comment: bingo. Apache error log says permission problem. now fixed. thanks! please put it to Answer.

Comment: I'm using Apache log4PHP in my PHP Laravel application and following is how I initialize the logger:
`Logger::configure(base_path().'/config.xml');`

and in config.xml:
`<param name="file" value="app/storage/logs/log.ERROR.log" />`

My application is deployed on Amazon EC2 and I grant the permission to storage directory as follows:
`sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage`

But still the log file is not created. How can I check that what's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper way of calling with config would be:

```
require_once('/path/to/log4php/Logger.php');
Logger::configure('/path/to/log4php.xml');
$logger = Logger::getLogger(basename(__FILE__));
$logger->info('Testing');
```

As Shivan Raptor stated, first thing to do is to check logs for permission problems.

Comment: This is not working for me from a command line script. Getting no error either. I see no log file being created.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this once**

It looks complicated at first, but it isn't.

**main.php**

```
require_once('/path/to/log4php/Logger.php');
Logger::configure('log4php.xml');

Class Log
{
    private $log;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->log = Logger::getLogger(__CLASS__);
    }
    public function myLog()
    {
        //this prints your data.
        $this->log->info("Hello, this is log here");
    }
}

//simply call the function
$log=new Log();
$log->myLog();
```

**log4php.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4php:configuration xmlns:log4php="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/">
    <appender name="fileappender" class="LoggerAppenderFile">
        <layout class="LoggerLayoutSimple" />
        <param name="file" value="/path/to/log/register-%s.log" />
        <!-- <param name="append" value="true" /> -->
    </appender>
    <logger name="Log">
        <appender_ref ref="fileappender" />
    </logger>
</log4php:configuration>
```

**Note** : Don't forget to give 777 permission to folders  :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but few errors found. Never never never use 777 permission (you don't want to create a security flaw, right?). Also with respect to object-oriented approach, never put a class in your main logic file. Use a separate file to store your class. Conclusion: re-consider your logic.

Comment: @Raptor Its only an example. But thanks for ur advice