# log php errors on console using log4php but it display on browser as well

Tags: php, log4php

i am using log4php library log errors only to console (stdout). But when I run my code on browser, it outputs on the browser, which I don't want to happen.

I already referred and tried 
[logs php error but not display it in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184881/logs-php-error-but-not-display-it-in-browser), but none of those answers worked out for me my code is simple.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
error_reporting(0);ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
require_once("log4php/Logger.php");
$logger = Logger::getLogger("main");
$logger->info("This is an informational message.");
$logger->warn("I'm not feeling so good...");
```

**Configuration file:**

```
<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/">
<appender name="default" class="LoggerAppenderConsole">
    <layout class="LoggerLayoutSimple" />
</appender>
<root>
    <appender_ref ref="default" />
</root>
```

This outputs on the browser,

> INFO - This is an informational message. WARN - I'm not feeling so good...

I want it to be only on stdout. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong about stodut in this case

EDIT MY WORKING CODE AFTER THE ANSWER:

```
<?php
require_once("log4php/Logger.php");
Logger::configure("log4php/config.xml");
$logger = Logger::getLogger("default");
$logger->info("This is an informational message.");
$logger->warn("I'm not feeling so good...");
```

Comment: Can you show your configuration file, please?

Comment: Included configuration file

Comment: You might need to check to see if [the script is being run via browser or console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042501/how-to-check-with-php-if-the-script-is-being-run-from-the-console-or-browser-req) and only run the logger if it's cli. If the script is being run via browser, stdout is the browser, not the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not calling file proper way ! or missing xml file

`require_once('/path/to/log4php.xml');`

So it should be something like this

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
require_once('/path/to/log4php/Logger.php');
//xml file here
$logger = Logger::getLogger(basename(__FILE__));
$logger->info('This is an informational message');
$logger->warn("I'm not feeling so good...");
```

See this question is well : [log4php : Cannot create log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485872/log4php-cannot-create-log-file)

Comment: Thanks :) I also found that there is an issue in my appender, I fixed it. I will include the updated code.

Comment: I am Glad you solved ! let me translate I dont understand, not english :)

Comment: One small doubt, To verify whether it is running in console. I tried

"php filename.php"

it displays the warning message.

While 

"curl url_path_to_file"

Is not showing any. Am I verifying it right

Comment: Yes! its right way! you can check here if need more info : https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4php/trunk/src/main/php/

Answer (score 0):

try

```php
ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

or set that directive in the php.ini file

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

in the documentation it says 

`Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any effect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed.`